# Return Records that span over two tables in a 1 to many relationship with multiple criteria on the many side

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to get a count of records of data that spans over three tables.  I have a table of products, a table of groups and a table showing which groups a product is in.  As below:

Product

| Product_ID | Product_Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A Product |
| 2 | Another Product |

Group

| Group_ID | Group_Name |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | Group A |
| 20 | Group B |
| 30 | Group C |
| 40 | Group D |

Product Grouping

| Product_ID | Group_ID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 |
| 1 | 20 |
| 1 | 30 |
| 2 | 20 |
| 2 | 40 |
| 3 | 50 |

I am trying to write a query that will, given the condition of group ids of say for example (10,20,30), it will return product 1.  And if I give group ids of say (20), it will return product 1 and product 2

I have tried:

```
select * from product_grouping
where group_id = 10 and group_id = 20 and group_id = 30
```

Answer (score 0):

Use aggregation and `having`:

```
select pg.group_id
from product_grouping pg
where pg.group_id in (10, 20 30)
group by product_id
having count(*) = 3;
```

If the product groupings can be duplicated, use `having count(distinct pg.group_id) = 3`.